# How is an NSNumber represented on disk?

Tags: objective-c

Not sure why Objective-C decided to use NSNumber instead of float, double, etc. How is this type represented on disk?

Comment: What's *disk* have to do with it? Did you mean "how is it represented in memory"?..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSNumber` is [toll-free bridged](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html) with `CFNumber`. In recent implementations of Core Foundation, `CFNumber` is a tagged pointer. This lets it be treated as an object, but without all the overhead of an object. Instead, the value is encoded in the object pointer (and isn't actually a pointer).

See [Tagged pointers and fast-pathed CFNumber integers in Lion](http://objectivistc.tumblr.com/post/7872364181/tagged-pointers-and-fast-pathed-cfnumber-integers-in).

Comment: +1: But it is only stored as a tagged pointer if the Number is an integer and the value will fit in the memory available.  Otherwise it is a full object (with all of the associated overhead).

Answer (score 4):

`NSNumber` is a descendant of `NSObject`, so it can go wherever an `id` can go: `NSarray`, `NSDictionary`, and so on. Primitives such as `int` and `double` cannot go in these classes, because they do not inherit from `NSObject`, and hence cannot participate in collections etc.

If I were to guess on the internals of `NSNumber`. I'd say it's a union and a type selector field. However, the beauty of encapsulation lets me successfully program to `NSNumber` without knowing a first thing about its representation (and not missing that knowledge).

Comment: Hopefully I read your mind correctly in the first sentence. Assuming it's similar to `CFNumber`, [the implementation](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635.19/CFNumber.c) is quite a bit more complicated than a union, perhaps to save a few bytes for smaller types.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw Thanks for the edit - indeed, you read my mind 100% correctly. Thanks for mentioning `CFNumber` as well: I know only the very basics of `CF` stuff, mostly to get by in situations when there's no "bridged" class. I'm very happy that this knowledge is not (or at least no longer) a core requirement to build working apps. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind is that Objective-C is a super-set of C, so they didn't decide to use `NSNumber` **instead** of the primitive types (float, double, etc.) but **in addition** to them.  If you don't need the functionality of `NSNumber`, then just use the primitive types and save the overhead of creating/destroying the objects.  Many functions in iOS (notably the array type functions) **only** work with **objects** (descendants of `NSObject`).  Therefore, if you want to pass some type of number to one of these functions, you need an object representation of it.  This is where `NSNumber` comes in.

To quote the documentation on `NSNumber`:

> NSNumber is a subclass of NSValue that offers a value as any C scalar
>   (numeric) type. It defines a set of methods specifically for setting
>   and accessing the value as a signed or unsigned char, short int, int,
>   long int, long long int, float, or double or as a BOOL. (Note that
>   number objects do not necessarily preserve the type they are created
>   with.) It also defines a compare: method to determine the ordering of
>   two NSNumber objects.

Note that internally the actual value is stored either as an integer or as a floating point number (within either a tagged pointer as Jay describes or a union in an object), depending on what value you are storing.  This is important to know as if you try to store a number like "32.1" it will store it as a floating point number and when you retrieve it you will most likely get something like "32.09999999999999".

As far as storing it to disk, if you need to do this then you typically store it with `encodeWithCoder` and retrieve it with `initWithEncoder` which converts it to a format intended to be saved to disk and later read back in.